Electromagnetic Question
May I know how do I solve for Question 2(a) and Question 2(b)?

I have got the wrong answer for this question 2(a) as shown in the second figure, but I don't know how a line is parallel to the y-axis and at the same time it is located at point x = 2m and y = -2m. Shouldn't it be at point x = 2m and z = -2m if it is parallel to the y-axis?
I have also attempted for question 2(b) and my trial solution is attached below which is the third figure. I don't know why my answer is not accepted. Is there anyone who could assist me with my confusion in these two questions?



"I don't know how a line is parallel to the y-axis and at the same time it is located at point x = 2m and y = -2m." I completely agree with you. It doesn't make sense. Perhaps it would make more sense if I had access to more context, though. I just can't say since I am only seeing what you've presented. Given what I see, the wording seems very strange. If something is parallel to the y-axis, only the x value is required (in an x-y basis system.)

@periblepsis Only if it's a straight line, if it's a curve it might only be parallel to the y axis at a single point.

@Finbarr When I take your suggestion of an arbitrary path of current on the x-y plane, regarding Biot-Savart, this is what I see. I may be wrong-headed, though. Feel free to set me straight. But if that's what you propose here, then the problem is still strangely worded to my view. The answer would then be infinitely small due to the infinitely short length, which is all that could be assumed if this is an unknown curve.
